# How do I bind react events from a mixin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to write a simple mixin for a tooltip. I already know how to bind my mixin to DOM events:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var el = this.getDOMNode();
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseenter, false);
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseleave, false);
},
```

...but I'd like to bind to the React events instead, to take advantage of its consistent event system. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to do this in the `render` method of the mixing component, by passing in the mixin's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers as props. I think one option might look like this:

```
var MouseMixin = {

    getMouseProps: function() {
        return {
            onMouseEnter: this.mouseenter,
            onMouseLeave: this.mouseleave
        }
    },

    mouseenter: function() {
        console.warn('mouseenter', arguments)
    },

    mouseleave: function() {
        console.warn('mouseleave', arguments)
    }
};
```

Then, in addition to mixing this in, you'd need to apply the behavior. In JSX in React 0.12, you can use the `...` spread operator to help with this:

```
var Example = React.createClass({

    mixins: [MouseMixin],

    render: function() {
        return (
          <div { ...this.getMouseProps() }>
              Hello world
          </div>
        )
    }

});
```

[See a working fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/s9jwrav8/1/)

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a good idea, but would be problematic if I want to use the tooltip on some element which already has its own `onMouseEnter` handler. So, well, you answered my question about binding events, now it's time for me to think about how to make it more generic.

Comment: To answer my own question: I decided that tooltips should be not mixins, but components. I wanted them to be mixins because I didn't want to introduce new DOM element just to handle the tooltip. It however turns out that I can create a "transparent" React element that would just pass its contents without creating a new (wrapping) DOM element. And *that*'s what I need.